# how to sort results by last day update at search result in plugin installer?

Tags: plugins, search

Is there any way to sort the results of plugin search result, by last update or whatever?

Comment: What are you referring to are you referring the results of http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=plugin&sort=new or are you referring to the search results for posts in your site or something else?

Comment: I'm referring to the plugin-install.php. It seems you can search plugin by name, but there is no way to sort the results, as in wordpress page.